# Creating a shared lib using CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a set of files (cxx and hpp) that I would like to make into a shared lib.  I would like to link that shared lib against My main application file (`InjMain.cxx`) to create the final executable.
Below are the following set of CMake commands that I use.

```
set(INJ_SRC
        src/functions/AFunction.cxx
        src/functions/BFunction.hpp
        src/functions/CInterface.hpp
        src/functions/DImpl.hpp
        src/functions/EInterface.hpp
        )

add_library(INJ_LIB SHARED ${INJ_SRC})      
add_executable(TEST_INJ src/InjMain.cxx)
target_link_libraries(TEST_INJ ${INJ_LIB})
```

The above doesn't seem to work. However if I use

```
add_executable( TEST_INJ  ${INJ_SRC} src/InjMain.cxx)
```

that seems to be working ok. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is `target_link_libraries(TEST_INJ INJ_LIB)`. `INJ_LIB` is not a variable, but the name of the library.

Comment: And with 5k+ reputation you should know that problem description "doesn't seem to work" is not suitable for Stack Overflow...